# Cake Relations with diffent name

Tags: cakephp, relational-database, relationship

I got a Table Users and a Table Groups. Every group has one GroupLeader.
So the field i use in is groupLeader ($hasOne) which contains a foreign key of users.

I cant manage to get that relation. So my question is, how to define a relation on a field with a diffent name.

thanks for a hint.
endo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You model should looks:

```
class Group extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Group';
    public $belongsTo = array('GroupLeader' => array(
                                                   'className' => 'User',
                                                   'foreignKey' => 'groupLeader'
                                                    )
                             );
}
```

Try with the above code. And ask if it is not worked for you.